# Connected to MongoDB but Express .get returns 404 error?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, models, mean-stack

I have an app using MongoDB + Mongoose on Express v4. I believe I have successfully connected my database, but my GET requests are returning a 404 error when I test the connection on Postman.

Could someone spot an error in my code?

Server.js

```
...
var mongo = require('mongodb');                      
var mongoose = require('mongoose');                
require('./models/Thread');
require('./routes/thread');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/pudo');   

var app = express();  
var router = express.Router();
...
```

/models/Thread.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ThreadSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
});
var Thread = mongoose.model('Thread', ThreadSchema);
module.exports = Thread;
```

/routes/thread.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Thread = mongoose.model('Thread');

router.get('/threads', function(req, res, next){
    Thread.find(function(err, threads){
        if(err){return next(err);}
        res.json(threads);
    });
});
module.exports = router;
```

I believe this is the minimal connections between my code in order for it to work. However, sending a GET to /threads returns a 404 error instead of any database records.

Comment: If mongodb connection is OK, please check the url used in your code...

Comment: Are you refering to this url `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/pudo');  `? It is correct

Comment: No, the url `get /threads`, please check the ip address and port listinning in your `app.listen()`...

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution! Instead of:

```
require('./routes/thread');
```

Use this:

```
router.use(require('./routes/thread'));
```